# Create array of dates/times between set hours

Tags: arrays, datetime, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to create a horizontal, ascending `ARRAY` of date/times but only including times that I specify (8:00AM-5:00PM).  I've tried using `NETWORKDAYS.INTL`, but that seemed to be more difficult and inevitably, did not render accurate results the way I was doing it (probably incorrectly).

```
February 1, 2020 8:00AM
February 1, 2020 9:00AM
[all hours in between]
February 1, 2020 4:00PM
February 1, 2020 5:00PM

February 2, 2020 8:00AM
[...]
February 2, 2020 5:00PM

February 3, 2020 8:00AM
```

I'm able to do the formula for the first day, but I'm stumbling at adding the following days.

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
=IF(
  AND(J2>=$E1+$B1,J2<$E1+$C1),
  J2+(1/24),
  J2-$C1+$B1
)
```

J2 = The first date in the array `=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1+[8:00AM]`

E1 = First day of the month `=EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1`

B1 = Start time `8:00AM`

C1 = End time `5:00PM`

Here is [my sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13Q2jIqHSxiGYF1yf8i6Yi5PgoprkHSmVKyfANbBdWOo/edit#gid=6355951&range=K2).  My formula is in K2 (currently dragging the formula across the row, but a single formula would be ideal.)

EDIT:
After playing with it and discovering `ROUNDDOWN` to extract the date, I came up with this:

```
=IF(
  AND(J2>=ROUNDDOWN(J2,0)+$B1,J2<ROUNDDOWN(J2,0)+$C1),
  J2+(1/24),
  ROUNDDOWN(J2,0)+1+$B1
)
```

Comment: I made an attempt at the logic for the completion date/time for projects that will go past the end of the day.  That formula is in G2.  So that's 3 formulae, G2,H2 and H3.  Everything else is manual entry.  lmk if it works.  (no work on sat/sun would be possible, but a bit trickier)

Comment: These are all such good solutions!  Thank you both for all of your effort!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work based on some other discussions we had.  it is an automatically generated array that will show just the date for the past 2 weeks. then the date and time for the upcoming two weeks, then just the date for 2 weeks after that.  You'll see the number 42 in the SEQUENCE portion of the formula.  this controls the overall number of days that the formula works for.  You'll also see TODAY()-14.  This is when the array is set to "start".

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(TODAY()-14+QUERY(SEQUENCE(42*24,1,0)/24,"where (Col1 % 1=0 and Col1<14) or (Col1 % 1=0 and Col1>=28) or (Col1 % 1<="&N(C1+0.000001)&" and Col1 % 1>="&N(B1)&" and Col1>=14 and Col1<29)",0)))
```

Comment: Trey, this is updated from where I was last night.  there was a small correction that needed to be made. the results are on the MK.Helpv2 tab.  Let me know if you want help on a single array to populate it with the actual schedule.

Comment: too shame that sequence cant handle decimal steps like: `=SEQUENCE(1,20,1,0.5)`

Comment: @player0 Yeah, but you can always divide the whole array by 2 (or whatever)

Comment: Very cool! Thank you!  Actually, the next logic I had in mind is breaking up a task into multiple days if it exceeds the ending hours.  For example, if the end hour is 5:00pm and the task wouldn't end until 8:00pm, suptract those 3 hours and add them to the following day(s).  But I'll dig into that and post it here when I don't succeed...

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(E1-1+
 SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(REPT(TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&
 DAYS(EOMONTH(E1, 3), E1))))&" ", 
 HOUR(C1)-HOUR(B1)+1)),,9^9), " ")+
 SPLIT(REPT(QUERY((ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&
 HOUR(C1)-HOUR(B1)+1))+HOUR(B1)-1)/24&" ",,9^9), 
 DAYS(EOMONTH(E1, 3), E1)), " "))
```

to change span from 3 months to one replace those two `3` for two `1`

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

shorter, faster, lightweight mathematical solution:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
 N(E1)+SEQUENCE(DAYS(EOMONTH(E1, D1-1), E1), 24, HOUR(B1))/24,9^9, 
 1+HOUR(C1)-HOUR(B1))),,9^9)),,9^9), " "))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

While this *does* solve my overall problem, it's not the ultimate formula I'm seeking which would be a single `ARRAYFORMULA`.

```excel
=IF(
  AND(J2>=ROUNDDOWN(J2,0)+$B1,J2<ROUNDDOWN(J2,0)+$C1),
  J2+(1/24),
  ROUNDDOWN(J2,0)+1+$B1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

### [@MattKing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11075129/mattking) solution:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1+QUERY(MOD(
 SEQUENCE(SUM({-1,1}*EOMONTH(TODAY(),{-1,D1}))*24,1,0)/24,{9^99,1}),
 "select Col1 where Col2<="&N(C1+0.000001)&" and Col2>="&N(B1),0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: happy to delete if you re-post it

Comment: you can delete. I reposted.

Comment: did you? this one is from your MK1 sheet (different than you posted)

Comment: ahh, you're right. Apologies.  I'm still new to the interface here.